# How do I use HTML signature with Apple Mail?

Tags: html, macos, email-client, apple-mail

I have used Mozilla Thunderbird for a long time, and created a well-polished **HTML signature** that works perfectly with Thunderbird.

How is it possible to use the same signature inside of **Apple Mail**? As far as I know, it does not support HTML signatures (which, perhaps, is a valid security policy, but works against the needs of our team).

If there is no way to inject the HTML code, what would be the better way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This varies depending on which Apple Mail/OS X version you're using.

The simplest thing to try would be to open your signature html file in Safari (Chrome and Firefox behave differently and would result in images being attached), copy it from there and paste it in the signature field in Mail > Preferences > Signatures.